# How to make a bash script that infinitely prints asterisks in the center of the terminal?

Tags: bash, loops

If I press the <kbd>L</kbd> key, the line will move to the left. If I press <kbd>R</kbd> key, the line will move to the right.

I managed to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
b="                            *                            "
while :
do

echo "$b"
read -s input

if [ $input==s ]
then
echo "${b:1}"
else
  if [ $input==d ]
  then
  echo " $b"
  fi  
fi

sleep 1

done
```

But I don't know how to do the input control without inserting "read" and blocking the cycle.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is it about printing an asterisk in the middle of the console? Or having a non-blocking read?

Comment: @A.Gille I think it is about how to move the asterisk using non blocking user input (i.e directionnal keys)

Comment: @Aserre, yes as you say

Comment: try `read -s -n1 -t1 input`

Comment: Also, `elif` instead of `else if`, or use `case`

Comment: Also, `[ $input = s ]` -- the spaces are crucial there: the `[` command does different things depending on **how many** arguments it receives. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Answer (score 1):

If you sleep one second anyway, you can also use the timeout option of `read`.

This will read up to one second for input:

```
read -t 1 input
```

When the return value of `read` is higher than 128, the timeout has been reached.  If it is lower, you have to wait.

```
if (( $? <= 128 )); then sleep 1; fi
```

By the way: this prints a star in the middle of the screen:

```
printf "%*s\n" $((COLUMNS / 2)) \*
```

`COLUMNS` is a variable, which contains the screen width. The number in front of the `s` format option says that the string should be aligned by that much spaces. And if you specify a star instead of a number `printf` reads the width from the command line.